# Program Crashes When Accessing array inside Struct

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, struct

I'm trying to implement the first part of an autocomplete feature that takes in a string, calculates an index for a particular letter, and then allocates another struct pointer at that index. It also stores possible completions of words in a string array. For some reason, the program crashes when I try to access the string array field, and I can't figure out why. How can I fix this?

Thanks

```
struct table {
    struct table *next[26];
    char **complete;
    int lastIndex;
    int size;
}; 

static struct table Base={{NULL},NULL,0,0};

void insert(const char *string){
    int index=string[0]-'a';
    if(Base.next[index]==NULL){
        Base.next[index]=(struct table*)malloc(sizeof(struct table));
        *Base.next[index]=(struct table){{NULL},NULL,0,0};
    }
    struct table *pointer=Base.next[index];
    if(pointer->lastIndex==pointer->size){     //expand complete array
            pointer->complete[pointer->lastIndex] = strdup(string); //program crashes here
            pointer->lastIndex=pointer->lastIndex+1;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird behavior often comes from undefined behavior caused by wrong memory manipulation. If you're experiencing **access violation** (segmentation fault), please try tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) to determine the root of the problem. Don't forget to define the term "crash".

Comment: `pointer->complete[pointer->lastIndex]` : `pointer->complete` is `NULL`. It can't dereference.

Comment: When you allocate the structure, you aren't allocating table.complete. That's a pointer to an/some pointer(s) so pointer->complete is undefined, as is pointer->complete [n].

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Your *fix-my-code* request is off-topic.

Comment: Read more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation and spend days reading some good C programming book.

Answer (score 2):

The crash in this line

```
pointer->complete[pointer->lastIndex] = strdup(string);
```

is because `pointer->complete` is `NULL`. In other words, you forgot to allocate memory for `complete`.

> How can I fix this?

You must allocate memory. It seems that you want a dynamic sized array of char pointers. So you'll need to use `realloc` so that you both extend the allocated memory and preserve previous values.

Something like:

```
char** tmp = realloc(pointer->complete, (pointer->lastIndex + 1) * sizeof(char*));
if (tmp == NULL)
{
    // Out of memory
    exit(1);
}
pointer->complete = tmp;

// Then you can do your normal code
pointer->complete[pointer->lastIndex] = strdup(string);
```

**Notice:** Though it's possible to use `realloc` every time you insert a string, it may perform rather bad.

So instead of reallocating memory for every new string, it may be better to reallocate a chunk of memory each time you call `realloc`. Like:

```
if (pointer->lastIndex == pointer->size)
{
    // Need more memory
    // - if it's the first time just start with 10 (or another number)
    // - else double the size
    pointer->size = (pointer->size != 0) ? 2 * pointer->size : 10;
    char** tmp = realloc(pointer->complete, (pointer->size) * sizeof(char*));
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        // Out of memory
        exit(1);
    }
    pointer->complete = tmp;
}
```

Here I decided to double the allocated memory when doing `realloc`. You can of cause use ant approach you like instead, e.g. always add 10 more instead of doubling.

BTW: The name `lastIndex` seems poor as it's really a `nextIndex` variable.

**A final word on data structure**

Your data structur, i.e. `struct table` seems a bit strange to me. At base-level, you only use `table`. At the next level you don't use `table` but only the other variables.

Seems to me that you should split up the struct into two structs like:

```
struct StringTable {
    char **complete;
    int lastIndex;
    int size;
}; 

struct table {
    struct StringTable strings[26];
};
```

That would save you both memory and some of the dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @SD'Anc - Notice that my original answer had a silly bug. It is corrected now.

Answer (score -1):

You are assuming that

```
const char * string
```

will contain only small case alphabets. Dictionaries also have apostrophes 
add that case.

Comment: Wrong about `static` (your answer describes `const`)